# Capacitance from Maxwell's equations

Tags: capacitance

I am trying to get the definition of capacitance nailed down. This is my work so far:
$$
\frac{\mathrm{d}U}{\mathrm{d}t} = \frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}t} \int_{\Omega_a}{ u(\mathbf{x},t)\mathrm{d}t} = \int_{\Omega_a}{ \partial_t u(\mathbf{x},t)\mathrm{d}t} = -\int_{\Omega_a}{ \mu_0^{-1}\nabla\cdot[\mathbf{E}\times\mathbf{B}] + \mathbf{E}\cdot\mathbf{J}\mathrm{d}t}\\
U(t) = \frac{1}{2}C[\phi(\mathbf{a},t)-\phi(\mathbf{b},t)]^2\\
\text{ Assuming C constant in time}\\
\frac{\mathrm{d}U}{\mathrm{d}t} = C[\phi(\mathbf{a},t)-\phi(\mathbf{b},t)]\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d} t}[\phi(\mathbf{a},t)-\phi(\mathbf{b},t)]\\
C\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}t}[\phi(\mathbf{a},t)-\phi(\mathbf{b},t)] = \frac{\frac{\mathrm{dU}}{\mathrm{d}t}}{[\phi(\mathbf{a},t)-\phi(\mathbf{b},t)]} = \frac{-\int_{\Omega_a}{ \mu_0^{-1}\nabla\cdot[\mathbf{E}\times\mathbf{B}] + \mathbf{E}\cdot\mathbf{J}\mathrm{d}t}}{[\phi(\mathbf{a},t)-\phi(\mathbf{b},t)]}
$$
So where can I go from here? I have never seen anyone talk about electrodynamics and capacitance at the same time. I guess there is some kind of dimensional analysis in play that allows certain approximations of the Maxwell equations?

Edit: $[\phi(\mathbf{a},t)-\phi(\mathbf{b},t)]$ should probably be an integral instead because there might be path dependencies.  Ended up doing dimensional analysis on Maxwell's equations by comparing how big the ratio of the fields from the different maxwell equations were, like E from Faraday's law divided by the (delta) E from Ampere's law wich contains a time derivative of E.

Comment: I'm confused about what your asking here.  What exactly are you trying to accomplish?  Are you looking for some general definition of capacitance in a certain context?  Are you attempting to show that a particular definition of capacitance is consistent with certain other statements in electrodynamics?

Comment: I am trying to find the capacitance as some limit of Maxwells equations, in short I need to know if I can use capacitance in my thesis right now I have seen people mentioning quasistatic but not under what conditions it is quasistatic. I want to derive the circuit equations and see when they apply kind of.

Answer (score 1):

Capacitance emerges solely from Poisson's equation (aka Maxwell 1):
$$ \boldsymbol{\nabla \cdot E} = \frac{\rho}{\epsilon_0} $$
That and the definition of voltage V:
$$ V = - \int \boldsymbol{E \cdot dl}  $$

It's strictly electrostatics.

Comment: I need to know the conditions for approximating the Maxwell equations as static though.

Comment: I mean the first equation is always valid and the second one is always valid when the time derivative of the vector potential is zero. Is that the criteria for electrostatics?

Comment: Almost. Electrostatics is equivalent to Coulomb's law:  no moving charges.  Hence the electric fields are constant and there are no magnetic fields at all.  [Magnetostatics considers situations with constant, divergenceless currents (divergenceless so that there are no charge build-ups, which would introduce changing electric fields).]

Comment: I will use capacitance anyway in my model... I will say since cA/V is small and v/c is small and the voltage propagation velocity times the typical wavelength is bigger than the system modeled it is okay. Do you think that is a reasonable motivation to use capacitance?

Comment: Sorry, I don't follow your configuration.  One, simple, justification for using a capacitance model is if the magnetic field energy is much less than the electric.  Then the magnetic fields are negligible (an ideal capacitor stores only electric energy).  A second, more-or-less equivalent, justification is if the gradient of the voltage is much larger than the time rate of change of the magnetic potential $A$, so that the line integral of $E$ is path independent and so forms a potential function.